# how can i read a file outside the app folder in android?

Tags: android

i need to make a compiler in android using the jflex and cup tools to read a file in the internal storage of the movile.

but the user need to input the path of the file and the user input its like:

```
/home/cp21.txt
```

but when i use the method openFileInput() it reads

```
/data/data/com.aplicattionpakagename/files/cp21.txt
```

and the file is in the buetooh directory of "Almacenamiento de telefono"

how can i read it?

Comment: Please post more complete code as what you say does not come through now.

Comment: In your post is nothing from what the subject suggest there would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something in external storage with [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

If you want the user interface to expose that as `/home`, make sure you do a String replace between your view and model, s.t. `/home` is converted to `/path/to/storage`, and vice versa.

Comment: one of the conditions its that its need to be in the internal storage of the phone, not in a external card o memory. work the same or i need to do something more?

Comment: External storage directory is NOT the external/removable micro SD card. But then i do not understand the answer as the user wants to use internal memory.